# Sushi rice does it have expiry date ?

Tags: rice, sushi

I have some sushi rice, In the packet the expiry date is given as Jan 2016, But the rice seems fine. Is it alright for me to use it to make sushi with it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is almost certainly a "best by" date, not an expiration date. [Still Tasty](http://www.stilltasty.com/articles/view/71) calls the shelf life of uncooked white rice "indefinite". Yes, you can cook and serve your rice assuming that it is free of contaminants.